# Regex Client Script

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I've an onChange Client Script which should change comma (,) to dot.

It works fine when you write a comma in the field, but if you write a dot it removes it, so 1.1 becomes 11.

Do anyone know why?

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }

    var fte = g_form.getValue('fte');

    if(fte.indexOf(',') > -1){
        var newStr = fte.replace(',','.');

        g_form.setValue('fte', newStr);
    }       
}
```

Comment: There is no regex used here, it's just string replacement.

Comment: Are you sure this code replaces it? And why to check of you have `,` in string? simply replace it. Also what's the point of last IF?

Comment: btw `ftw.replace(',','.')` will replace only first matched occurrence.
You should use `ftw.replace(/,/g,'.')` to replace all matched occurrences

Comment: @Justinas accidentally copied the code twice...

Comment: Do you use some front-end framework? As your function call looks like some kind Angular watcher and not simple `<input onChange="onChange()">`. Can you provide working SO Snippet with issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() and join() function for replacing the character in a string

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }

    var newStr = g_form.getValue('fte').split(',').join('.');

    g_form.setValue('fte', newStr);
}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Got the following error: "onChange script error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded function onChange_resource_plan_fte_1(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) { if (isLoading || newValue === '') { return; } var fte = g_form.getValue('fte'); var newStr = fte.split(',').join('.'); g_form.setValue('fte', newStr); }"

Comment: can you try to debug by adding console.log("newStr",newStr)  after the "var newStr = fte.split(',').join('.'); "

Comment: If I write 1.1 newStr becomes 11

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your client script:

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
    if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
        return;
    }

    g_form.setValue( 'fte',  g_form.getValue( 'fte' ).replace( /,/g, '.' ) );
}
```